# windows server 2016 patching - how to show options?

Tags: windows-update, operating-systems, windows-server-2012-r2, windows-server-2016, patch

when checking for patching updates on windows server 2012 it allows you to select what updates you want to install:

[image]

for example:

[image]

However, on windows server 2016 it does not allow you to select what to install and it does not show you how big are the files do download:

It simply shows this:
[image]

Question:

Is there a way to change this `feature` so that it shows me what is there that could be downloaded\installed and how big each update is, and allows me to select which ones I want to do?

How can I achieve that?

Patching is at least a monthly activity in my job.

Comment: They changed the way Windows Updates are deployed on Windows 10, which includes any version of Windows Server based on Windows 10, what you want is not possible.  You can deploy updates to Windows Server by using your own WSUS.  WSUS gives you the ability to only deploy the updates you want installed.

Comment: I believe you are talking about this: [Deploy Windows 10 updates using Windows Server Update Services (WSUS)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/update/waas-manage-updates-wsus)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updates in Windows 10 are "all-or-nothing". The option to be selective has been taken
away, because Microsoft decided that this is safer for the users.
(And they might have been right.)

Microsoft did give you the option to uninstall updates selectively,
from the Start menu executing "View installed updates", where you may right-click
an update and choose "Uninstall".

Microsoft is currently saying that its May 2019 major release will restore
*some* of your control over Windows Update, although I don't know of the exact details.
See for example the article:
[Microsoft’s Windows 10 May 2019 Update puts you back in control of updates](https://www.theverge.com/2019/4/4/18294944/microsoft-windows-10-may-2019-update-features-availability-control-updates).

Until that time, other solutions are:

- Examine an update's properties such as size on the
  [Microsoft Update Catalog](https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Home.aspx),
  where you may download individual updates.
- Use
  [WSUS](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-server-update-services/get-started/windows-server-update-services-wsus),
  as recommended in the comments, although this solution is a bit heavy to implement.
- Use third-party products of which the best-known ones are listed below,
  although they are mostly aimed at Windows 10, so it is not sure that they
  also work on Windows Server:

  - [WuMgr (Update Manager for Windows)](https://github.com/DavidXanatos/wumgr)
    Free and open-source.
  - [Windows Update MiniTool](https://www.majorgeeks.com/files/details/windows_update_minitool.html)
    Closed-source and dating from 2016. You may read a review
    [here](https://chefkochblog.wordpress.com/2018/03/19/guess-whos-back-whdownloader/).