# patching - how to download all the need updates and apply them later on?

Tags: windows-update, download, windows-server-2012-r2, windows-server-2016, patch

When doing patching on windows servr 2012 you can choose which updates to download\install.

that is [different for Windows Server 2016](https://superuser.com/q/1432166/730576).

anyway, as you can see on the picture below, sometimes there are massive files to download, and these should be applied in several servers - for example the SQL Server 2016 Service Pack 2 Cumulative Update (CU) - shown below, will need to be applied in at least 3-4 servers.

How can I download it once, instead of downloading it again and again for each server?
And then, obviously, use this downloaded file, in each relevant serve.

Is there a way to do this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can google the KB number and you'll find the [direct download](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=56975) for that update. You can download it and run on as many machines as you wish.

You can also use [WSUS Offline](http://download.wsusoffline.net/) which will download all updates for a chosen OS and install what's missing.

Comment: +1 nice to meet you WSUS - it seems very interesting